# "Un-require" a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

My WP theme's parent functions.php has

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';
```

inside that file is a function I want to change. The problem is there's a bunch of other functions in there that I don't want to touch. I could just copy the whole file into child theme and unregister/unequene that file. I was wondering if there is an easier way.

inside template-tags.php the function I want to change values in is called

```
function web2feel_content_nav( $nav_id ) {
```

... content i want to change in here

```
endif; // web2feel_content_nav
```

It is called in my single.php file using

```
<?php web2feel_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```

It was easy to just change the parent file, but I don't want to touch the parent, so I just want to override that one function and change it to the new/fixed one.

Comment: @nada this is not possible outside of classes. if you do this, you will get a fatal error (`Cannot redeclare foo()`)

Comment: you tried that http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove functions, and neither can you redeclare them as this will lead to a fatal error.

Unfortunately you haven't given any more context on your problem, so I cannot give you an exact solution. Based on this, there a three solutions to this problem

### SOLUTION 1

This is the fastest and easiest solution, but rest on the fact that the parent theme's function should be wrapped in the following condition

```
if ( !function_exists( 'NAME_OF_FUNCTION' ) )
```

If this is the case, you can simply copy the parent function to your child theme as is and without the conditional statement, make your changes and your good to go. This is the only time you can redeclare the same function as the above condition first check if a function exists with the same name in the child theme, and if there is, it simply ignores and skips the parent function

### SOLUTION 2

This is also quite fast and easy and relies on filters. If the parent theme has build in filters, you can simply alter the function through the filters provided. In your child theme you can simply create a function to alter the filter and then hook that to the appropriate filter to alter the function's output

### SOLUTION 3

This is the effort solution where non of the above conditions are met. This is your last and only resort.

What you should do here is

- Copy the parent function to be modified to your child theme and **rename** that function to whatever unique name suits you
- Modify this function as needed and safe it
- You now need to copy the affected templates to your child theme, in your case `single.php`.
- In these templates you will need to replace all instances of the old function with your newly created function and safe them

Wordpress will now load the templates in your child theme ( in your case the child `single.php` ) instead of the parent template. This will ensure that the page is loaded with your new modified function

Comment: I used your Solution 1 since it was wrapped in an if statement, I didn't see that earlier. Thanks for the help!